# Mule custom connector to connect to stack overflow site (Java)

Tags: mule, mule-studio, connector

I am trying to create a custom connector to connect to stackoverflow site using Mule ESB(Mule studio). I should be able to post queries to site through my application.

Can anyone please provide me some pointers to tutorial /examples or sample code for mule custom connector?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the best place to start, the Mulesoft DevKit documentation has basic tutorials moving up towards more complex examples:

https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/Anypoint+Connector+DevKit